# How to deploy your web site (client only) in one click?

Tags: node.js, web, upload, host, demo

The issue that I have encountered: 
As I Developed Web Client in Angular 2 for a customer, I have wanted to demonstrate it when i was in middle of development.

but couldn’t found a really fast and temporary way to host my client so he will be able to review the current state of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I will make such a tool that will help others, this tool inspired by the WeTransfer flow… 
very simple without the need of registration.. and without setting up any environment…

**The tool is targeted for:**
web developers / UX designers to demonstrate their work to customers / QA /friends in one click.

**The need:** 
    Demonstrate and Share your web client app with Customers / QA / Friends.

**The Solution offered** 
very simple flow  -
1.  Fill up your email
2.  Select your web client zip from your computer.
3.  The site have uploaded and run!
4.  You get the link of your online site to the email, and you can share it with your friends / QA / Customer.

**What is the benefits of using the system:**
1.  Costs – the hosting is for free (the site will be live only for 1 week per upload)
2.  Time – you don’t need to register to hosting server, you don’t need to setup environment.

**What you should know:**
 - It is only hosting web client applications and not servers. 
 - It can host angular / react… or just plain Html , JS, Css and other assets
 - It should not be used for Production as it expired after a week and as you cannot setup a DNS …

**What is it for me:**

- In the future I will make features for paying users:
  a.  The ability to manage the site
  b.  longer periods of the live site
- Helping the community.

The URL of the tool: http://showoffweb.com

**Will appreciate your feedback,**